# how to use retract boolean value in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to use retract's returning value?

I just want to make function to print out words, instead of boolean value, 
so I try to compare the retract value to print the statement but it seems not working.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please show your code, what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate `retract/1` can succeed or fail, just like any other predicate.

---

```
:- assert(a).

test :-
   retract(a),
   writeln('a used to be true, but not any more.'), !.

test :-
   writeln('a was false').
```

In the example above, when evaluating `test.`, `retract(a)` succeeds, so the `writeln('...')` is evaluated, which always succeeds.
After that, a cut, so we can't backtrack to the second clause.

---

```
%:- assert(a).

test :-
   retract(a),
   writeln('a used to be true, but not any more.'), !.

test :-
   writeln('a was false').
```

In this example, with the `assert(a)` being commented out, `retract(a)` fails, so we get to the second clause of `test/0`, which succeeds by writing "a was false".

Comment: Glad to help. Don't to forget to accept the answer if it helped you (you can do that by clicking the check mark next to it).